# Move files from a document library to a list SharePoint 2010

Tags: list, document-library

I need to move files from a document library to a list. I there a way other than programmatically to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint list and SharePoint library are not same.

**SharePoint library** - is a place on a site where you can create, collect, and update files with others.

**SharePoint list** - used to store data across columns in separate rows. You can think of a list as a table in a database that will have columns and rows. items in the list can have files as attachments.

Please provide us precise information about your requirement, so that we can provide you with the best solution to fulfill your requirement.

hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to confirm, what I already know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it manually (upload multiple files) or you can use PowerShell to transfer files.
This could help: [[LINK]](https://recordpoint.zendesk.com/entries/23270406-How-to-create-a-PowerShell-script-to-move-a-document-within-a-site-collection)

Answer (score 0):

Files and list items are fundamentally different in the Sharepoint universe. If you need to transfer files to items, you'll need to create a list item and add the file as an attachment.